# Is bad to read/write from a database serialized data at every page load?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, database-design, optimization

I'm thinking of storing serialized data (usually 1-3kb in a TEXT column) in a database, however I'm concerned whether or not it'll be resource expensive. 
At every page load, the data is read, and by the end of the page load, the data is written back into the same field, if it has been altered (thinking of having some type of checksum to do this).

Would it just be better to avoid doing this? Or should I use files instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Using database is better than using files.

2) If the serialized data can be mapped to a database table, it's better. If not, you're doing it right.

Remember, [the TEXT, BLOB, etc columns are not stored inline with the rest of the fields of the table.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-requirements.html) For BLOB and TEXT data, the information is stored internally in a different area of memory than the row buffer.

Comment: What do you mean by "stored inline with the rest of the table"?

Comment: @Kevin, it means, "the TEXT types are stored outside the table itself". This helps in getting the rows quickly. As TEXT/BLOB can contain large amount of data.

Comment: Oh, okay. I'll probably end up trying not to use the database.